# Word Web Add-in - Alinhamento do conteúdo do Footer

Tags: javascript, c#

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um add-in para o Word, seguindo o template no visual studio.

Hoje, com o código a seguir, tenho o resultado quase finalizado. Porém, no Footer, não consigo de forma alguma (das quais já tentei e pesquisei) alinhar este **bendito** texto à direita.

Além disto, como poderão ver, tem uma imagem no header, esta imagem não está exibindo em 100% de largura pois a página possui uma margem. Eu gostaria que ela ficasse 100% de largura no Header. Como poderia?

> **Código:**

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var mySections = context.document.sections;

    context.load(mySections, 'body/style');

    return context.sync().then(function () {

        var myHeader = mySections.items[0].getHeader("primary");
        myHeader.clear();


        myHeader.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(imgHeader, Word.InsertLocation.start);
        myHeader.insertContentControl();


        var myFooter = mySections.items[0].getFooter("primary");
        myFooter.clear();

        myFooter.insertHtml("<p align='right'>São Paulo ∙ Brasília</p><p align='right'>www.google.com.br</p >", Word.InsertLocation.start);
        myFooter.insertContentControl();

        return context.sync().then(function () {
            console.log("Added a header for the first section.");
            console.log("Added a footer for the first section.");
        });

    });
})
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug Info: " + JSON.stringify(err.debugInfo()));
        }
    });
```

> **Resultado em imagem:**
>
> **Header gerado com o código acima**

[image: Header do Documento Word, gerado pelo fonte acima]

Comment: Tente colocando um _style_ em vez de _align_: `style="text-align: right"`...

Comment: Eu já tinha tentado este método. Tem o mesmo efeito que este que mostrei acima.

Comment: Tem que usar o Dev Tools (F12) do navegador pra ver como estão sendo exibidos esses <p>, se há algum CSS interferindo etc..

Comment: Então sam, o problema é que meu VS já abre direto no Word da minha máquina... Isso já padrão, só em startar a aplicação. Teria uma forma de configurar pra rodar na web, eu já tento. Seria realmente uma boa saída

Comment: Aí eu já não sei. :/